# App Crashes When Connecting a MapKit View using IBOutlet

Tags: swift, xcode

When I add a MapKit View to my viewController using storyboards, the app runs as it should.  The crash occurs as soon as I add an IBOutlet connection.  The error I get is this `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f9f36897080> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key managerDelivOverviewMapBG.'`  I've deleted and remade the connection a few times, but it keeps crashing whenever one is made.  I have done this a few times in my app already, and this is the only place where I cannot add a connection to a MapView.

EDIT: For whatever reason, no fix I could find worked, so I attempted to move on and just not use a map view which is when I realized my problem wasn't with the map view at all, because no matter what connection I made to any element, the app still crashes, so I wound up deleting the whole view controller and remaking it, which although inelegant, solved the problem.

Comment: delete your derived data folder clean your project and try again.

Comment: Ive tried this a few times and it diddnt work @DanielLyon

Answer (score 0):

Is the ViewController Custom Class set correctly in the Storyboard?

[image: Example]

Make sure you added it to the ViewController Custom Class and not to the View Custom Class.

Also, after changing it, make sure to delete the old @IBOutlet and add new ones.

You can also check all the outlets connected to the View Controller by right clicking it on the left panel of the storyboard.

[image: View Controller outlets]

If you see an yellow warning sign in any of your outlets it means that it lost the connection and you need to add it again.

Comment: Did everything exactly as you said, and it still diddnt work